# Exporting mailadressen to CSV

Tags: powershell

I want our Marketing deparment to extract all mailadressen from our users to CSV.

I created and Constrained Endpoint by using a configuration file, but i keep getting errors

First i created the config file:

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Path 'c:\marketing.pssc' -SessionType 'RestrictedRemoteServer' -LanguageMode FullLanguage -ModulesToImport ActiveDirectory -VisibleCmdlets ('Get-ADUser', 'Get-ADGroupMember', 'Export-Csv', 'Select-Object')
Register-PSSessionConfiguration –Name ‘Marketing’ -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI –Path ‘c:\marketing.pssc’
```

Im trying to run this code:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -Scope Process -Force

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName name -ConfigurationName 'marketing' 

Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "groupname" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | where {$_.mail -ne $null} | Select Name,Mail | Export-CSV -Path "\\somepathto\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```

i Expect an CSV file with name and email adressen.
The script works when running as a domain admin, currently i get this error:
The term 'where.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program....

Comment: Change `where` to `Where-Object` and whitelist that too. Are you expecting the CSV file(s) to be created on your machine, or on the remote machine?

Comment: I changed this and the error is gine, now i get the next error:

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument "Mail" does not belong to the set "ModuleName;Namespace;OutputType;Count;HelpUri;Name;CommandType;ResolvedCommandName;DefaultParameterSet;Cmd
letBinding;Parameters" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `get-aduser` commandlet, you should provide at least a required input param. Currently, it is stating the one you provide(-properties) is not approved by the validateset of the input param set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

This will help you out:
`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(mail=*marketing)' | select-object Name,Mail`
https://ss64.com/ps/get-aduser.html

Comment: i need to get the mailadresses from the users in the AD group. I do not need to filter the adresses afterwars. This code gives me the same error

Comment: Hi @Denskie, I get your point. But the mail addresses aren't objects that can be retrieved on their own, those are properties of AD-objects. So I hoped by pointing to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#required-parameters) we should find a way to have proper input parameters set/provided so we can grab the mail property from the returned object(s). Does this input make more sense?

Comment: Hi, im new to powershell. I dont understand why the script works perfectly when running with a domain admin user and not with the configuration file. Does filtering the Get-aduser command change this?